# What is wrong with my Matlab implementation of Horner's method?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I have the following matlab code, which uses the method of false position to find the roots to any given polynomial. In this case the polynomial is being evaluated by Horner's method.

```
   % Find a roots using the method of false position.  
   % The initial interval is [a,b]
   % and the iteration stops when b-a<tol.

function c=falseposition(a,b,tolerance,cons,n)
format long
fa = horner(cons,n,a);
fb = horner(cons,n,b);
if fa==0
   c=a; return
end
if fb==0
   c=b; return
end


c=0.0;
newc=1.0;
while (newc-c)>tolerance
   fa = horner(cons,n,a);
   fb = horner(cons,n,b);
   c = (fa.*b - fb.*a)/(fa - fb);
   fc = horner(cons,n,c);
   if fc==0
       return;
   end
   if fa*fc<0
       b=c;
   else
       a=c;
   end
   newc = (b.*fa - a.*fb)/(fa-fb);
end
```

Where

```
% Horner's Method Implementation.
% The given polynomial is evaluated by the function horner.
% For example to evaluate 1+ 3*x^2 -8*x^4 we write the array to 
% passed as cons=[1 0 3 0 -8].

function y=horner(constants,sizee,xx)
format long
y=constants(sizee);
for i=(sizee-1):-1:1
    y=(y.*xx) + constants(i);
end;
```

which i call by

```
a=[8 -5 -2 1]
falseposition(-3, 2, 1.e-6, a, 4)
```

But it gives me an answer that is way off.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, false position method works only if f(a) and f(b) are of opposite signs. So my suggestion would be to check this before iterating i.e.
   `fa*fb<0`.
2. The solution to your problem is that you do **not** need `newc`. And your while loop should start as `while (b-a)>tolerance`